# Possibly incorrect IL gets emitted when using a combination of unsafe statement and a branch

Tags: c#, unsafe

Here's a very simple C# console application / Framework 4.5 and compiled using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. It reads a double from an array of bytes, with a simple range check beforehand.

```
class Program
{
    private static byte[] fData = new byte[8];

    public static unsafe double ReadDouble(int offset)
    {
        if ((offset + 8) > fData.Length)
            return 0;

        double value = 0;
        fixed (byte* pBuffer = fData)
            value = *((double*)(pBuffer));

        Console.WriteLine("This code is never reached!");
        return value;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        fData = BitConverter.GetBytes(1234.56789d);

        double result = ReadDouble(0);

        Console.WriteLine("result: {0}", result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When compiled without */optimize* flag, Any CPU configuration it outputs the following (and the IL generated seems a bid dodgy):

```
result: 0
```

When compiled with */optimize* flag, it correctly outputs:

```
This code is never reached!
result: 1234,56789
```

Any ideas on why this is the case?

PS: If the range check is commented out ( *if((offset ...)* ), then the it outputs correct result again.

EDIT: Here's the IL that gets generated for ReadDouble() function, notice the absence of Console.WriteLine

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    float64 ReadDouble (
        int32 offset
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2060
    // Code size 81 (0x51)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] float64 'value',
        [1] bool,
        [2] float64,
        [3] uint8& pinned pBuffer,
        [4] uint8[]
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.8
    IL_0003: add
    IL_0004: ldsfld uint8[] WeirdBug.Program::fData
    IL_0009: ldlen
    IL_000a: conv.i4
    IL_000b: cgt
    IL_000d: ldc.i4.0
    IL_000e: ceq
    IL_0010: stloc.1
    IL_0011: ldloc.1
    IL_0012: brtrue.s IL_0020

    IL_0014: ldc.r8 0.0
    IL_001d: stloc.2
    IL_001e: br.s IL_004f

    IL_0020: ldc.r8 0.0
    IL_0029: stloc.0
    IL_002a: ldsfld uint8[] WeirdBug.Program::fData
    IL_002f: dup
    IL_0030: stloc.s 4
    IL_0032: brfalse.s IL_003a

    IL_0034: ldloc.s 4
    IL_0036: ldlen
    IL_0037: conv.i4
    IL_0038: brtrue.s IL_003f

    IL_003a: ldc.i4.0
    IL_003b: conv.u
    IL_003c: stloc.3
    IL_003d: br.s IL_0048

    IL_003f: ldloc.s 4
    IL_0041: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0042: ldelema [mscorlib]System.Byte
    IL_0047: stloc.3

    IL_0048: ldloc.3
    IL_0049: conv.i
    IL_004a: ldind.r8
    IL_004b: stloc.0
    IL_004c: ldc.i4.0
    IL_004d: conv.u
    IL_004e: stloc.3

    IL_004f: ldloc.2
    IL_0050: ret
}
```

Comment: Note that the array created in `fData = new byte[8]` is thrown away by `fData = BitConverter.GetBytes(1234.56789d);`

Comment: If you think your MSIL is dodgy, show it....

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the suffix for decimal is m. The suffix for double is d.

Comment: Oh my Gooood, you're right. Time to go out walking...

Comment: In your MSIL, there are *two* locals of type `double`, one is the return value, and `value` is a different one.  Are you sure this comes from the same version of the source code?

Comment: @BenVoigt The second double is actually there for the short-circuit / early return - it stores the return value of the method.

Comment: @Kel Are you sure this is the exact code to reproduce your issue? It works just fine for me, debug or release, optimized or not, JIT with debugger or without. And the IL is very different as well.

Comment: @Luaan: Look closer, there's no transfer from `value` to the local used for the return value.  And the return paths are unified, the extra local isn't for *early return* but for all returns.  So it didn't come from this source code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I know. That's where the IL seems garbled - when I get the IL from my compiler, it correctly uses it for all returns, but it does also store the `value` in it if applicable. In either case, it uses two locals - one for `value`, the other one for the return value. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough :)

Answer (score -1):

You potentially have a problem with misalignment.  Some Intel floating-point instructions fixup misalignment for you, some newer ones (SIMD ones) don't.

You probably should stick to the `BitConverter` class for this.

The other option is to use unsafe code for the other direction of the conversion -- the actual array will be `double[]`, and you can case `double*` to `byte*`.  In general casting `T*` to `byte*` is safe, and the reverse is not.